# Show any $k$ dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ is the set of solutions of some linear system $\bf{Ax}=\bf{0}$ st. $rank(A)=n-k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

The question is,

> Let $V_k$ be any $k$ dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^n$, then there exists some $n\times n$ square matrix $\bf A$ st. $V_k$ is the set of all solutions of linear system $\bf{Ax}=\bf{0}$, and ${\text {rank}}({\bf A})=n-k$, or equivalently ${{\text {ker}}(\bf{A})}=V_k$

I have difficulty proving above theorem. Hope someone could help.

The converse of this theorem, i.e. the solutions of $\bf{Ax}=0$ is a subspace of dimension $n-{\text {rank}} ({\bf A})$, is by rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $e_1,..,e_k$ be a base of $V_k$, complete it to a base $(e_1,...,e_k,e_{k+1},..,e_n)$, define $f(e_i)=0, i\leq k, f(e_i)=e_i, i\geq k$. Now take $A$ the matrix of $f$ in the base $(e_1,..,e_n)$.